# Possible way to hack Solidity into executing a function directly from a struct as a method? (v0.8.20)

Tags: solidity, struct, compiler, function, hack

```
pragma solidity 0.8.20;

contract SolidityLimitTest {
    mapping (address => Hack) private Hackable;

    struct Hack {
        uint amount;
        function(uint) returns (uint) ten_x;
    }

    function ten_x(uint x) private pure returns (uint result) {
        return x * 10;
    }

    // The contract compiles, but this function reverts on execution.
    function rabbitHole() public returns (uint) {
        uint a = Hackable[msg.sender].ten_x(1);
        return a;
    }
}
```

I was limit testing Solidity code today and found to my surprise that the above code compiles correctly (although `rabbitHole()` reverts). Could this mean that there is an unofficial way to get
functions listed as properties of structs to execute as methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a perfectly legitimate use. Only there are some restrictions: the called function must be executed within the context of the same contract. You can read the official documentation: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/types.html#function-types

I've expanded your example a bit so that the functions return values.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

contract SolidityLimitTest {
    mapping (address => Hack) private Hackable;
    uint public z;

    struct Hack {
        uint amount;
        function(uint) returns (uint) f3;
    }
    constructor(uint _z) {
        z = _z;
        Hackable[msg.sender] = Hack(20, ten_x);
    }

    function ten_x(uint x) private pure returns (uint result) {
        return x * 10;
    }

    // The contract compiles, but this function reverts on execution.
    function rabbitHole(uint a) public returns (uint b) {
        b = Hackable[msg.sender].f3(a);
    }


    function f1(uint a, function(uint) pure returns(uint) b) internal view returns(uint) {
        return a + b(z); 
    }

    function f2(uint a) public returns(uint) {
        z = f1(a+z, ten_x);
        return z;
    }
}
```